# Unable to Install RMarkdown

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, r-markdown

I am trying to install Rmarkdown on Rstudio.

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")
```

I receive error messages that include:

```
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/z6/pjv553zn1bb39ldgph2klbt40000gn/T/RtmplQkOZY/R.INSTALL7213    13a123d/stringi':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
```

(I also receive other error terms such as

```
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘stringi’ is not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stringr’
```

There are a few of these that would take up too much space in this question post.)

I have a Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5, and downloaded an xcode on my computer that should have supplied the C compiler, but is not read in rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

Sir try this:

```
install.packages("stringi", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
install.packages("stringr", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

Then rerun the `install.packages("rmarkdown", dependencies=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me out Facottons! These are the messages that I received. for 'install.packages("stringi", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))', 'configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/z6/pjv553zn1bb39ldgph2klbt40000gn/T/RtmpPd4yJN/R.INSTALL4a71da937a2/stringi':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘stringi’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/stringi’'. I can add the entire code into a separate "Answer" under this question.

Comment: It seems you're using the 3.2 version. Do you have the same problem in the last R version (3.3.3)?

Comment: I have a 2010 Mac that can only be updated to a 10.7.5. I am unable to download R 3.3.3 because it requires a Mac 10.9 or higher to run.